# Pagination with perpage data selection

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I'm using pagination and I didn't find the option to show data per page like 15 30 60 120. 
Is there any way to get the per page selection filed with laravel pagination, if no then please suggest me any altenate.

Comment: You can use [Chumper Datatable](https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create a tradition combobox at HTML for per page selection.

at the controller get the value and pass the value to paginator method like this:

```
$perPage = $request->get('perPage'); 
User::paginate($perPage);
```